# Layers and styles for all different geometric objects

Tags: geoserver, layers, style

I want to change the graphical style of my geoserver map.

There are like 400 different geometric objects and 20 different zoom-levels.

Do I have to create 8000 (400x20) different layers/styles and upload all of them to my geoserver?

We have a university project called OHDM (Open Historical Data Map):

- [OHDM on GitHub](https://github.com/OpenHistoricalDataMap)
- [OHDM Page](http://ohdm.net/)

If you check out the layer previews from the geoserver of this project, you can see, that they tried to create 228 different layers by hand.

Our goal is to change the style to something like [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.de/karte.html) looks like.

Comment: Please stop posting the same question again and again without adding the details we asked for before - the short answer is **no** you don't need 8000 styles. Please read up on how [SLD works](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/introduction.html), OSM styling (as seen on https://geoserver.org) is [available](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/osm-styles) if that is all you need.